# Index 5 out of bounds for length 5 when trying to add an element to an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, exception

```
public static Groceries [] addGrocery(Groceries[] arr, String name, int price) {
        int arrayLength = Array.getLength(arr);
        System.out.println(arrayLength);
        Groceries[] newGrocery = new Groceries[arrayLength + 1];
        int arrayLength2 = Array.getLength(newGrocery);
        System.out.println(arrayLength2);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            newGrocery[i] = arr[i];
            System.out.println("New item added" + i);
        }
        newGrocery[i+1] = new Groceries(name, price);
        return newGrocery;

    }
```

I have this method where I input an array containing 4 objects and it creates a new array of objects copying the previous 4 objects and then adding one more to the array. But I keep getting this exception.

Comment: `Array.getLength(newGrocery)` why not just `newGrocery.length`?

Comment: You need to write `newGrocery[i] = new Groceries(name, price);` because `i` has already been increased 4 times in the loop. Increasing it again with `i + 1` will get you out of range for the new array. It would be better to write `newGrocery[newGrocery.length - 1] = new Groceries(name, price);` instead, so that you're not dependent on `i`

Comment: Note: always have variables with the smallest scope possible. For example: declare your loop counters WITHIN the for loop `for (int i ...)` ... because that ENSURES that you won't use that `i` afterwards. And just for the record: as you seem to be allowed to use library methods from the Array class ... that class has a method that  copies content from one array into another. There is no need to do that manually. Besides learning how to loop arrays and not go "off by one" in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurred because you're trying to add an element to an array index `(i+1)` that just doesn't exist, here:

`newGrocery[i+1] = new Groceries(name, price);`

Its because `i` has already been incremented by the for loop at the end to the last index value in the array, by doing `i+1` you're trying to access the `index = arrayLength2` which doesn't exist.

May be what you want is a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) that is capable of expanding its size when a new element is added, unlike array which has a fixed size.

Comment: I thought I made the new array length to be 1 index larger than the old array length with this though? ```Groceries[] newGrocery = new Groceries[arrayLength + 1];```

Comment: Right, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Ah I see now tyvm!